# Adding Parcelable interface to a class from external library

Tags: java, android, downcast

1. I'm using an external library for 3rd party map retrieving in Android.
2. There's a class that I want to pass through Intent, so I want to make it implement `Parcelable`.
3. But the class is from the external library.

What's the best practice to do in this case?

What I did was:

1. Create a custom class that extends this class(let me call it `A`) and implement Parcelable
2. But when I get all these `A` class instances from the library's network request, I found out that I can't cast it to my custom class object since it's casting from parent class to child class.
3. So I added a static method that can copy member variables from `A` class to newly instantiated custom object's member variables, which literally converts external library class `A` into my custom class.
4. It does work, but it looks like a code smell. How can I improve this? Or is it not a code smell?

Comment: (But when I get all these A class instances from the library's network request, I found out that I can't cast it to my custom class object since it's casting from parent class to child class), You can down casting in java, Did you tried.

Comment: @user7790438 for sure, but when you, let's say `A a = new A(); B b = (B)a;`(when b is a child class of A), down casting does not work. It only works when `A a = new B(); B b = (B)a;`. And I don't have control over the instantiation phase of the `A` class. The library gave it to me in the form of `ArrayList<A>` after network request as a callback.

Comment: Then you don't choice than the one you did.

Comment: yeah maybe it's best I can do

Answer (score -2):

Ideally any pojo you use in android be parcelable.
If not, the way you have done is an alternative and is not a code smell. Chill